# python dynamic import for test scripts execution using eval

Tags: python

I am working on a framework that basically tries to run test scripts from a package containing all the scripts.

on my execution driver file:

currently what i am doing is, `from testscripts import testscript1`, `from testscript import testscript2` and so on.

and i am taking script name from `sys.argv[1]`

```
test_name = sys.argv[1]
```

and using `eval` function to run that script.

testscript skeleton:

```
##testscript1.py
class testscript1:
    def runTest():
        {
            ## tests to run
        }
```

The eval function call:

```
eval(test_name+"."+test_name+".runTest()")
```

For this to work i need import each test script name separately. 
What i want to do something like from testscripts import *.

If i do this then i get an `error: name 'testscript1' is not defined.`

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I think you have some syntax issues.

Comment: @omri_saddon : where should i be correcting the  syntax. please help.

Comment: `from testscripts import *` imports all symbols from testscripts/__init__.py if it exists. It does not import anything from its [submodules](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules). You may explicitly import anything you need in `testscripts/__init__.py` for your code to work.